# Button not working on surface view

Tags: android, button, addition, surfaceview

I've was studying on some source code from this link 
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/add-overlay-on-camera-preview.html

what should i do here if i want to add another button, i've added button in xml, but they are not working, their source code is:

```
LinearLayout layoutbg = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
    layoutbg.setOnClickListener(new LinearLayout.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case (R.id.previous_btn):
            //some source   
showImage();
                break;

            case (R.id.next_btn):
    //some source           showImage();
                break;

            }

        }

        private void showImage() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this, " User don't  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

    });
    }
```

Comment: what error did you get ?post logcat trace if so?

Comment: i didn't receive any error, the app runs fine...but the buttons are not working,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make your Activity implement `View.OnClickListener`

After that in your `onCreate()` method do:

```
Button btn1= findViewById(R.id.previous_btn);
Button btn2= findViewById(R.id.next_btn);
btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

In the OnClick() Method that you have to override after implementing `View.OnClickListener` do the following:

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case (R.id.previous_btn):
            //some source   
showImage();
                break;

            case (R.id.next_btn):
    //some source           showImage();
                break;

            }

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should add the listener directoy to the buttons, not to the LinearLayout... and using `View.OnClickListener`

Just go to the second part of the tutorial you linked, "next:
- Implement takePicture function of Android Camera", there is the code to add a listener to a button.

Answer (score -1):

The problem could be within your XML. Android tends to draw views that are on the bottom of your XML document last. This means that if your buttons are sitting higher in the document than the surface that's on top of them, the user's clicks will be hitting your SurfaceView and not your buttons.

For example, your button would not be clickable in this case:

```
<RelativeLayout
  ... >
    <Button ... />
    <SurfaceView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But would be in this case:

```
<RelativeLayout
  ... >
    <SurfaceView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button ... />
</RelativeLayout>
```